# get music from Mixcloud/soundcloud and use with own player?

Tags: soundcloud

I want to make a website with my own audio player (with waveform.js but own styled), but at the same time take my audio tracks from soundcloud or mixcloud, is this possible? 
I have read the documentation for soundcloud api and realized that yes, but to be sure I need to check in practice.
Therefore, I decided to ask you first, is it possible to take from soundcloud or mixcloud mp3, artist name, trackname and count of likes (count both from my site and sc/mc)? If not, what parts of native sc/mc player I have to use at least?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I already explained the detail answer in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792944/using-the-soundcloud-apis-resolve-from-vb-net-plus-very-general-questions/38143725#38143725](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792944/using-the-soundcloud-apis-resolve-from-vb-net-plus-very-general-questions/38143725#38143725)

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible using the soundcloud api.

```
<audio src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TRACKID/stream?client_id=CLIENTID" controls="true" preload="auto"></audio>
```

replacing TRACKID and CLIENTID with their respected values.

Comment: Thanks! and soundcloud api allows to synchronize count of likes and listens at the soundcloud and on my own website?

Comment: yes all of those values are available from the soundcloud api using the /tracks resource

download_count 
playback_count
favoritings_count

simply add those values to your own and display. (you can not change or update the soundcloud counts manually.)